# Replacing the character period to morse code equivalent messes up the TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to replace all of the characters to their morse code equivalents. I used the textBlock.Text.Replace() method to accomplish this and it worked fine until I reached the period character. When I try to replace it with ".-.-.-", it works fine BUT all of the other characters are now messed up. Before the period character, everything worked great.

Here's the code

```
namespace PivotApp1
    {
        public partial class Textmorse : PhoneApplicationPage
        {



            public string[] aakkoset = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", 
                                         "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", 
                                         "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
                                         "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", 
                                         "U", "V","W", "X", "Y", 
                                         "Z", "Ä", "Ö", "0", "1", 
                                         "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
                                         "7", "8", "9", "?", ":",
                                         ",", "@", "/", "=", " ",
                                         "."};

            public string[] morse = { ".-  ", "-...  ", "-.-.  ", "-..  ", ".  ", 
                                      "..-.  ", "--.  ", "....  ", "..  ", ".---  ", 
                                      "-.-  ", ".-..  ", "--  ", "-.  ", "---  ", 
                                      ".--.  ", "--.-  ", ".-.  ", "...  ", "-  ", 
                                      "..-  ", "...-  ", ".--  ", "-..-  ", "-.--  ", 
                                      "--..  ", ".-.-  ", "---.  ", "-----  ", ".----  ", 
                                      "..---  ", "...--  ", "....-  ", ".....  ", "-....  ", 
                                      "--...  ", "---..  ","----.  ", "..--..  ", "---...  ",
                                      "-....-  ", ".--.-.  ", "-..-.  ", "-...-  ", "  ", 
                                      ".-.-.-"};

            public Textmorse()
            {

                InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void TBoxText1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {

                CreateMorseText();

            }
            public void CreateMorseText() 
            {
                tBlockMorse1.Text = TBoxText1.Text.ToUpper()
                    .Replace(aakkoset[0], morse[0])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[1], morse[1])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[2], morse[2])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[3], morse[3])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[4], morse[4])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[5], morse[5])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[6], morse[6])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[7], morse[7])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[8], morse[8])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[9], morse[9])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[10], morse[10])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[11], morse[11])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[12], morse[12])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[13], morse[13])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[14], morse[14])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[15], morse[15])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[16], morse[16])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[17], morse[17])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[18], morse[18])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[19], morse[19])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[20], morse[20])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[21], morse[21])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[22], morse[22])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[23], morse[23])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[24], morse[24])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[25], morse[25])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[26], morse[26])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[27], morse[27])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[28], morse[28])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[29], morse[29])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[30], morse[30])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[31], morse[31])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[32], morse[32])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[33], morse[33])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[34], morse[34])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[35], morse[35])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[36], morse[36])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[37], morse[37])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[38], morse[38])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[39], morse[39])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[40], morse[40])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[41], morse[41])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[42], morse[42])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[43], morse[43])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[44], morse[44])
                    .Replace(aakkoset[45], morse[45]);        
            }

            private void TBoxText1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                TBoxText1.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just a stab in the dark..but have you tried Trim() on the string[] morse array elements you have ".- " the space, should it be there..?

Comment: Im with the answers below.  Just do the period first.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I think the space is intentional.  But good on you for raising the point: the OP probably wants to add a `.Trim()` at the end of the method chain, if, for example, input is "SOS" and the desired output is "... --- ..." without a trailing space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the period replace `.Replace(aakoset[45], morse[45])` to the beginning.

What is likely happening is that you're replacing all your characters with dits (periods) and dashes, and the when the "period" get's replace, it sees all your "dits" as periods.

Answer (score 8):

You do understand why this is happening, don't you?  When you search for periods, there's no way to distinguish which periods are there because they were in the original string, and which ones are there because they are part of the morse code sequence of some other character.

Do the period first, or, more robustly, iterate through the string once, and replace each character as it comes.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still a bit new at this so I didn't think about it that way. But it does make sense, now that I think about it.

Comment: @AllanHaapalainen: You can save us all a lot of angina and circumvent the next three questions you will be asking on this subject *if you just separate the input textbox from the translation output*.  1) Watch for changes to the input textbox 2) when a chance occurs, clear the translation output 3) translate the input to the output char by char 4) profit.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a dictionary or some sort of KeyValue pair collection

[This page](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MorseCode.aspx) has a good example.

Comment: @L.B: `string.Join(" ", intput.Select(x=>_codes[Char.ToUpper(x)]))`

Answer (score -1):

Do all the periods first instead of last? D'OH! Too slow.